# NSException error in CollectionViewController

Tags: ios, swift, collectionview

I don't know what's wrong with my code dealing with the CollectionView. The compiler shows an error saying that terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException. Another TableViewController works fine with the same data model. It throws the error when I click on the tab bar for the collection view.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class MemeCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {
var memes: [Meme]!
@IBOutlet var memeCollectionView: UICollectionView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    memes = appDelegate.memes
    createRightBarButtonItem()

}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    memes = appDelegate.memes

}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(true)
    memeCollectionView.reloadData()
}

func createRightBarButtonItem() {
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(
        title: "+",
        style: .plain,
        target: self,
        action: #selector(goToViewController))
}

func goToViewController(){
    let createMemeViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CreateMemeViewController") as! CreateMemeViewController
    present(createMemeViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return memes.count
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "MemeCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! MemeCollectionViewCell
    let meme = self.memes[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]
    cell.memeCollectionImageView?.image = meme.memedImage

    return cell
}
```

}

Comment: Post any other information about the error message... set a breakpoint (or a few) so you can step through and find out exactly when it happens.

Comment: Can you try initializing the variable 'memes' at the point of declaration to some empty Array and see if it works..